# How to use event subscriptions with Botkit 0.6

Tags: node.js, slack, slack-api, botkit

I'm working on a Slack app using Botkit 0.6, and I'm having trouble with getting the events to work. I've tried following the [documentation](https://botkit.ai/docs/provisioning/slack-events-api.html), but I can't make sense of what I specifically need to do in order to pass the Request URL.

The goal of this is to notify the app whenever someone posts a message, then check their userId to see if it matches a list, and if it does, the program advances from there. I have this working for direct messages and direct mentions, so I am just trying to transition it to all messages.

Am I just overlooking something simple? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For the 0.6 branch, the URL is https://yourbot.com/slack/receive.  that url needs to be added to Slack *after* your bot app is running, as Slack has to validate the URL before it will be considered valid.

Comment: Alright, what would I have to add code-wise for this to work?

Comment: Update: I changed it and now it says that the verification request timed out, so that's progress